# SQL: How to delete row meeting criteria from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am able to identify the data I want with a select statement:

```
SELECT  InventoryUnitMeasure.ItemCode, 
        InventoryUnitMeasure.UPCCode,  
        InventoryItem.ItemName
FROM InventoryUnitMeasure 
   INNER JOIN InventoryItem 
         ON InventoryUnitMeasure.ItemCode = InventoryItem.ItemCode
where ItemName like 'SNT%'
```

I then try to change to delete the column UPCode in table InventoryUnitMeasure like so but get an error:

```
DELETE upccode from
FROM dbo.InventoryUnitMeasure
  INNER JOIN  InventoryItem 
     ON InventoryUnitMeasure.ItemCode = InventoryItem.ItemCode
where ItemName like 'SNT%'
```

I know I'm making a simple mistake but I just cannot figure it out and I've tried looking on multiple sites and multiple searches but I can only see how to delete a whole table when joining and not just a column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am using SQL Server as DBMS.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? SQL Server?

Comment: Are you trying to delete a *row*, or a *column*? Those are two very different things...

Answer (score 3):

Isn't DELETE statement used for deleting whole row? As i underestand your question, you should probably use UPDATE statement instead..

```
UPDATE table dbo.InventoryUnitMeasure SET upcode = null ...
```

Some hint on syntax can be [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/faizanahmad/archive/2009/01/05/join-in-sql-update--statement.aspx) (quick google search)

Comment: +1 For posting a link to multiple solutions for several DBMSs, since it wasn't specified by the OP.

Comment: Update table is exactly what I wanted to do.  Thanks, Pida, for seeing through my question to what I really wanted to know!
For future people with similar questions this was for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE InventoryUnitMeasure.upccode 
FROM dbo.InventoryUnitMeasure
    INNER JOIN  InventoryItem 
     ON InventoryUnitMeasure.ItemCode = InventoryItem.ItemCode
where ItemName like 'SNT%'
```

this should work

Comment: I don't know of any DBMS which lets you specify a column in a `DELETE FROM` statement.  He's either trying to remove the entire row (since he's associating it with another row), updating that specific column to some value that represents deletion, or wanting to alter the structure of the table to remove the column... but this won't work for any of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

have you noticed that  there are two FROM  statements one after another? Just change the beginning of your delete statement as DELETE FROM table_name ....

If you wish to update a value of a cell under a certain column then Píďa is right. If you wish to delete the whole column from a table then you should use 
ALTER TABLE table_name

DROP COLUMN column_name

that means you are changing the structure of that table.